# Host Wordpress site on the domain/hosting purchased from GoDaddy

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, wordpress-rest-api, godaddy-api

I have a blog website completely build with wordpress.com, let's say the current domain is: https://abcd.wordpress.com
Since I have posted few blogs on the website, now I want to purchase domain and web hosting.
For example, I want domain to be: https://abcd.com instead of https://abcd.wordpress.com

I need help in purchasing the required domain and I am not aware that how I can move my content from previous domain(https://abcd.wordpress.com) to new domain(https://abcd.com) that I will purchase.

Also, as of now I am using free version of wordpress.com so many ads are getting published on my website. If I purchase domain and web hosting from GoDaddy then will these ads get removed or should I have to buy domain and web hosting from Wordpress itself like the Wordpress personal or premium plan?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Login to wordpress.com hosted website admin panel and then follow the steps below:

a) Go to Tools from the left side menu
b) Then click on Export
c) Then select All content
d) Click on the export button

2. Before purchasing domain and hosting setup WordPress website on local computer
3. If website is working properly on local computer and you are happy with it then proceed with domain and hosting purchase
4. You will get more control on website when you will move website to GoDaddy or any other hosting platform. But WordPress.com provides more security if we use their limited plugins and themes. So pros and cons are there
5. You can deactivate the website hosted on WordPress after successfully migration to other platform

Comment: Thanks Tushar. Is it necessary to migrate to localhost? Second, everytime if I update website content through wordpress admin, should I have to export again and again?

Comment: If you buy a domain name and buy hosting space with any provider you will upload a new instance of wordpress cms and import your own instance of wordpress cms to it (following the export example given above). It has nothing to do with your previous instance of wordpress. You will no longer need to access the old one (abcd.wordpress.com) because everything will be done on the new one. Tushars advice about localhost is optional if you simply want to migrate it to the new host.

Comment: Thanks @Aliqua for your response. Can you please share any guide from where I can get the steps to perform uploading and importing operations with Godaddy?

Comment: I dont know their products personally. You'll have to read their FAQ/guides.